# Leer el teclado con un servicio en segundo plano en Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

Tengo un servicio en Python en una Raspberry Pi que se encarga de leer de un teclado y enviar una petición a una API al pulsar una tecla.

Cuando lo ejecuto en el terminal funciona correctamente. Sin embargo, cuando lo ejecuto como un service no recibe ningún input tanto del teclado conectado a la raspberry como el de la máquina conectada por SSH.

```
import tty
import sys
import termios
import requests
import json

orig_settings = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)

tty.setcbreak(sys.stdin)

input = ""
clave = "xxxxxxxx"

while True: 
    key = sys.stdin.read(1)[0]
    if key == '*': 
        input = ""
        print("Input reset!")
    elif key == "#":
        url = 'https://localhost:3001/openMainDoor'
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        data = {'key':clave, 'mainDoorCode': input}
        response = requests.put(url = url, data = json.dumps(data), 
headers = headers, verify=False)
    
    if (response.ok):
        print("Code correct!")
    else :
        print(response.reason)

    input = ""   
else :
    input = input + key
    print(input)

termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, orig_settings)
```

El servicio se activo de la siguiente manera:

```
[Unit]
Description=Load Python Service.
After=multi-user.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 keypad.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/aperturaCentro/
StandardInput=tty-force
Type=simple
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Cómo haces la ejecución como servicio?

Comment: [Unit]
Description=Load Python Service.
After=multi-user.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 keypad.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/aperturaCentro/
StandardInput=tty-force
Type=simple
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target